# How we use Shift+Enter for line break in NSTextField- Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I want to line break using shift+enter in TextField(Control+Enter is working)
I don't want to use TextView because using this Enter Key Action is not performing..

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to do this is option-return, and it works for free.

Comment: yes my requirement is shift+enter... like in skype when we type message then shift+enter works

Answer (score 2):

With this code when user presses Enter key you can sent an comment for example and when user presses Shift+Enter key the default behaviour of NSTextView is executed which it is to insert an line break. In my opinion this is a better solution than to use an NSTextField in this case.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if (aSelector == @selector(insertNewline:)) {
        NSEvent * event = NSApp.currentEvent;
        if ((event.modifierFlags & NSShiftKeyMask) != NSShiftKeyMask) {
            //Do some when only the enter key is pressed
            return YES;
        }
    }
   return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it: Within `control:textView:doCommandBySelector:` of `NSTextFieldDelegate`, capture the `insertNewline:` command and check if the current event has the shift modifier flag.

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)fieldEditor doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector {
    if (commandSelector == @selector(insertNewline:) &&
        [[[NSApplication sharedApplication] currentEvent] modifierFlags]
        & NSShiftKeyMask) {

        [fieldEditor insertNewlineIgnoringFieldEditor:self];
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if a text view would be more appropriate for your app than a text field, then that's what you should use.

I wrote one that can send action messages. Here's [the header](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/translate-text/src/tip/PRHActionTextView.h) and [the implementation](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/translate-text/src/tip/PRHActionTextView.m). It's under [a BSD license](https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/translate-text/src/tip/LICENSE.txt).

Comment: It works some time... some time its not works.... when works then work only for 1st time... it works for enter key which is near numeric key....but shit+enter is still issue

Comment: anything which tell us ..is shift key pressed??

Comment: can I use this function for NSTextField , I tried but not able to achieve it.

Comment: It's not a function. It's a subclass of NSTextView that is able to send action message. Such a subclass is unnecessary for NSTextField because NSTextField is already able to send action messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Peter it works
I add following in code
    int flags = [event modifierFlags];
    BOOL shift = ( flags & NSShiftKeyMask ) ? YES : NO;

```
if (([event keyCode] == enterKey1 || [event keyCode] == enterKey2) && !shift) {
    window = [self window];
    [window makeFirstResponder:[window contentView]];

    [NSApp sendAction:action to:target from:self];
}
```

but now able to set focus on texView after action
on textField I was using [textField selecttext];

for TextView I tried [theTextView setSelectedRange: NSMakeRange(0,0)];
but not works